# Error when parsing a URL using Android code

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML from a URL using Android. When I ran my app, I'm receiving the following error:

```
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 29, column 854: mismatched tag
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:519)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:478)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:317)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at com.first.MyApp.MyApp$downloadSaAsnyc.doInBackground(MyApp.java:970)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at com.first.MyApp.MyApp$downloadSaAsnyc.doInBackground(MyApp.java:1)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
06-04 10:57:50.250: W/System.err(16811):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

The XML from a URL that I'm trying to parse looks like this...

```
<ScheduledAudienceResponse>
    <ScheduledAudiences>
        <ScheduledAudience>
            <audience_id>1</audience_id>
            <audience_name>Jones Kapate</audience_name>
            <firstname>Jones</firstname>
            <lastname>Kapate</lastname>
            <id_number>123434</id_number>
            <branch_id>164</branch_id>
            <audience_group_id>8</audience_group_id>
            <scheduled_date>2012-06-04</scheduled_date>
        </ScheduledAudience>
        <ScheduledAudience>
            <audience_id>4</audience_id>
            <audience_name>John Doe</audience_name>
            <firstname>John</firstname>
            <lastname>Doe</lastname>
            <id_number>12312</id_number>
            <branch_id>164</branch_id>
            <audience_group_id>8</audience_group_id>
            <scheduled_date>2012-06-04</scheduled_date>
        </ScheduledAudience>
    </ScheduledAudiences>
</ScheduledAudienceResponse>
```

The code I'm using to parse the XML code above looks like this...

```
String sa_target_url = "http://my.app.com/scheduled_audiences/scheduled_audience_xml/" 
                        + username + "/" + password + "/" + current_date + "/"
                        + device_id;

Log.v( LOG_TAG, "sa_target_url: " + sa_target_url );

URL sa_url = new URL( sa_target_url );

sa_url.openConnection();

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

ScheduledAudienceHandler myScheduledAudienceHandler = new ScheduledAudienceHandler();

xr.setContentHandler( myScheduledAudienceHandler );
xr.parse( new InputSource( sa_url.openStream() ) );
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you are wrong at this line `xr.parse(new InputSource(sa_url.openstream()))`.Try changing to `xr.parse(new InputSource(sa_url.getInputStream()))`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it didn't work....

Comment: > go through the following link [SaxParsing Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/10/android-full-app-part-3-parsing-xml.html)

Comment: Based on the exception I'd guess that either the XML is malformed or your running into a character encoding issue. Can you check what the runtime response looks like and what tag is being mismatched at line `line 29, column 854`?

Comment: Thanks MH, I got malformed XML. Got it solved now. :)